# What is used in South America to search flights? (something like Kayak, etc)?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, south-america

What is used in South America (for example Chile) to search flights?
I am looking for something similar to Kayak, cheaponair, but I want to know the most popular site there. I need to find a good flight deal from Santiago to Rome.

PS. And yes, I am preferably looking for something in English or Spanish (and possibly somewhere person with Chilean creditcard.. etc can pay)

Comment: Can't you use Kayak in South America?

Comment: Well. I am not sure. They have version of the site for Brasil. I am not sure if person in Chile can buy from there.

Comment: @Armen: If you don't mind whether the website is in English, Portuguese, or Spanish it might be worth saying so in the question. I wonder if there are also websites in Dutch or French in the Guyanas (-: For all I know there's one in Quechua ...

Answer (score 10):

I am a frequent and addict traveler, I live in Mar del Plata, Argentina. The best, and perhaps the only site that you can search and buy, cheap flight and hotels, is called [DESPEGAR](http://www.despegar.cl) (something like Expedía, Orbits etc.). (And if you go to the bottom of the page, you can find the links for other countries in Latin America) 
In most of them the costs are shown in local currency.

Have a good experience in Latin America.

Comment: Too bad the website is only in Spanish. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Spanish is bueno :)

Answer (score 4):

When i flew in, to and from South America to Europe i used a combination of Skyscanner.net and looking up individual airlines.

Skyscanner forwards you to the airline's website once you have found the flight that you want to know more details about.

Once you visit the airline website, try to view the airline websites in Spanish, sometimes you will get a better price. Be sure to read terms and conditions thoroughly though as some special offer prices are only available to residents of certain countries and if you attempt to use a ticket which was a special offer and the airline see that you don't fit the rules of the promotion they will charge you a whole lot more on the spot to board the flight.

Answer (score 3):

There are also metasearch engines in South America.

[Trabber has a version in Chile](http://www.trabber.cl) and several other countries of the region.

Comment: @Vince: I do not understand your comments :(. Besides Trabber, I am sure that there are other metasearch on available in South America.

Comment: my bad I misread your answer.